# I cannot fix the buttons in the project

Tags: flutter, button

I'm developing an application with flutter. But I cannot fix the buttons in the project. On my chat page, the button goes up. I'm new to the Flutter language, can you help me?

Hello, I'm developing an application with flutter. But I cannot fix the buttons in the project. On my chat page, the button goes up. I'm new to the Flutter language, can you help me?

Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

My Button Code :

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<TabItem> tabItems = List.of([
    new TabItem(Icons.home, "Anasayfa", Colors.blue),
    new TabItem(Icons.message, "Sohbet Odası", Colors.orange),
    new TabItem(Icons.person, "Profil", Colors.red),
  ]);
  int seciliPozisyon = 0;
  CircularBottomNavigationController _navigationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigationController =
        new CircularBottomNavigationController(seciliPozisyon);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Crypto App"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            child: bodyContainer(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
          ),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: bottomNav())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget bodyContainer() {
    String activeUserId =
        Provider.of<AuthorizationService>(context, listen: false).activeUserId;
    Color selectedColor = tabItems[seciliPozisyon].color;
    switch (seciliPozisyon) {
      case 0:
        return HomeScreen();
        break;
      case 1:
        return FriendlyChatApp();
        break;
      case 2:
        return Profile(
          profileId: activeUserId,
        );
        break;
    }
  }

  Widget bottomNav() {
    return CircularBottomNavigation(
      tabItems,
      controller: _navigationController,
      barHeight: 60,
      barBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      selectedCallback: (int selectedPos) {
        setState(() {
          seciliPozisyon = selectedPos;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

ChatApp Code :

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    FriendlyChatApp(),
  );
}

final ThemeData kIOSTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  primaryColor: Colors.grey[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
);

final ThemeData kDefaultTheme = ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
  accentColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
);

String _name = '';

class FriendlyChatApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FriendlyChatApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.text, this.animationController});
  final String text;
  final AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor:
          CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut),
      axisAlignment: 0.0,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(child: Text(_name[0])),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(_name, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: Text(text),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = [];
  final _textController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _isComposing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS //new
            ? BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
                ),
              )
            : null,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
                itemCount: _messages.length,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(height: 1.0),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
              child: _buildTextComposer(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onChanged: (String text) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isComposing = text.isNotEmpty;
                  });
                },
                onSubmitted: _isComposing ? _handleSubmitted : null,
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: 'Mesajınızı Buraya Yazınız:'),
                focusNode: _focusNode,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                child: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                    ? CupertinoButton(
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)
                            : null,
                        child: Text('Gönder'),
                      )
                    : IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)
                            : null,
                      ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) {
    _textController.clear();
    setState(() {
      _isComposing = false;
    });
    var message = ChatMessage(
      text: text,
      animationController: AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
        vsync: this,
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      _messages.insert(0, message);
    });
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
    message.animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var message in _messages) {
      message.animationController.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add :

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

Here as shown:

```
Scaffold(
      //here 
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
      
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Crypto App"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            child: bodyContainer(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
          ),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: bottomNav())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here using this whenever user will type something setting value to false will make keyboard overlap the bottom navigation bar.

Hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I added it but ran into the following error: The named parameter 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset'.dartundefined_named_parameter

Comment: @NisaEfendioglu I have edited my answer. Can you see it again. Mention that property in scaffold.

Comment: It happened. Thank you so much. :)